# Promisify without object instance

Tags: javascript, node-promisify

We can promisify mysql pool `getConnection` function if we have already created the pool, like this:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const util = require('util');

const mysqlPool = mysql.createPool(CONFIG);

const getConnectionPm = util.promisify(mysqlPool.getConnection).bind(mysqlPool);
```

And the usage can be something like:

```
(async() => {
    const connection = await mysqlPool.getConnectionPm();

});
```

How can I promisify the `mysqlPool.getConnection.query` function to use `connection` variable? To make something like this:

```
(async() => {
    const connection = await mysqlPool.getConnectionPm();

    const result = await connection.queryPm(SQL_QUERY, SQL_ARGS);
});
```

The problem is that I don't know how to pass the `connection` variable to the promisify function. I guess one different way is to create a connection object with `getConnectionPm` function, then bind the query to that object like what we did to promisify the `getConnection` itself. But how we can achieve something like the code above?

For example, the code below gives an undefined error:

```
const getConnectionPm = util.promisify(mysql.createPool.getConnection);
```

Comment: what about `util.promisify(connection.query.bind(connection))`?

Comment: @Lux I can do something like `mysqlPool.getConnectionPm = util.promisify(mysqlPool.getConnection.bind(mysqlPool));
`. But I don't have the connection variable to promisify it before getting the connection from `getConnection` function. Something like this doesn't work `util.promisify(mysqlPool.getConnection.query.bind(mysqlPool.getConnection))` because the query is undefined.

Comment: Just promisify later then after you've created the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your getConnectionPm, and add a `queryPM` promisified query method to each connection.

```js
const getConnectionPm = async () => {
    const conn = await util.promisify(mysqlPool.getConnection).call(mysqlPool);
    conn.queryPm = util.promisify(conn.query).bind(conn);
    return conn;
}
```

Then you can query as in your example.

```js
(async() => {
    const connection = await mysqlPool.getConnectionPm();
    const result = await connection.queryPm(SQL_QUERY, SQL_ARGS);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think we should create another variable after defining the `conn` to call it and create a connection instance, because in the third line `conn.query` is not defined. It worked after this change.

Comment: That's odd. `await` should've created an instance of `Connection`. Are you sure you added `await` in front of `util.promisify(mysqlPool...)`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it again, the exact error is `The "original" argument must be of type Function. Received type undefined`, which happens when I'll try to access `conn.query`. I don't think that's a valid assumption on what's `await`s job. Actually we don't need `await` there, but for creating a connection from this `conn` function. I've edited the code.

Comment: Ok I found my mistake. I didn't actually call `getConnection`. I needed to add `()` at the end of the first line like `util.promisify(mysqlPool.getConnection).bind(mysqlPool)()`.